# Android: ListView inside TabHost

Tags: listview, android-layout, android-tabhost

I'm assigning a ListActivity as a Tab contnet. Everything is working fine, but I'm not able to see all the list item results. I'm seeign 2 items only that to the half of the 2nd item only visible, i know my list contains more than 100 items. 
Any guesses?

+++++ EDIT ++++

```
Tab view Layout:
================

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip"
                android:background="#000" />
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:background="#696969" />
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:background="#000" />
            <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </FrameLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>


Tab Activity:
=============
onCreate():

        mTabHost = (android.widget.TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getLocalActivityManager());
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);

        Intent list1Intent = new Intent(LIST1);     
        View tabview1 = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "Tab1");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(tabview1)
                .setContent(new Intent(list1Intent)));

        View tabview2 = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "Tab2");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(tabview2)
                .setContent(commentsIntent));                               
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);      


LIST1 layout:
=============
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rootView">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/cs_list_empty"
        android:text="No Data"></TextView>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#E6E8E9" android:dividerHeight="2dip" 
        android:clickable="false" android:choiceMode="none" android:focusable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,
Venkat Papana

Comment: Are you able to see all items when you put the listview outside the tab host?

Comment: Yes @blessenm, it is working fine outside of tabhost.

Comment: If you have any errors in log cat put that up. Or put your code up.

Comment: hi @blessenm, updated my original question with my code. please check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the scrollview with ListActivity as it already implements scrolling and the scrollview will interupt the optimisations made for the list activity.

Make the tabcontent framelayout as

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
```

This will make the framelayout to fill the entire remaining space.

Comment: Thank you, it is working for my list views, but i have problem with scrolling if one of my tabs contain a long linear layout with several views.. (not list view). Can you please suggest me how to resolve this.. thank you

Comment: Hi @blesenm, ignore my previous comment. I have fixed linear layout scrolling by placing linearlayout inside a scrollview. like:
     <TabHost>
  <LinearLayout >
   <FrameLayout>
    <!-- TAB1 (not a list view)-->
    <ScrollView>
     <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- TAB2 (list view) -->
    <LinearLayout ></LinearLayout>
   </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>`